# Add Hours, minutes and seconds to Spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a Spark SQL function to add Hours, Minutes and Seconds to existing timestamp column.

For example:

```
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        dt|             txn_dt|          txn_dt_tm|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|2008-08-15|2008-08-15 00:00:00|2008-08-15 05:00:00|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I need add 23 hours 59 minutes and 59 seconds to `txn_dt` column.

Output:

```
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        dt|             txn_dt|          txn_dt_tm|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|2008-08-15|2008-08-15 23:59:59|2008-08-15 05:00:00|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**Update:**

I was able to get it using INTERVAL, but not sure this is efficient way of doing it.

```
df.select((F.col("txn_dt") + F.expr("INTERVAL 23 HOURS") + F.expr("INTERVAL 59 MINUTES") + F.expr("INTERVAL 59 SECONDS")).alias("txn_dt_tm"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to customize the udf function, such as:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val timeUdf = udf{(time: java.sql.Timestamp) => new java.sql.Timestamp(time.getTime + 24*60*60*1000 - 1000)}
df.withColumn("dt", timeUdf(df("dt"))).show()
```

and the result:

```
+--------------------+---+
|                dt| id|
+--------------------+---+
|2008-08-15 23:59:...|  1|
+--------------------+---+
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, let me check that. But also, using `Interval` i was able to get the same..